# confusing solutions to $x + {\frac {1}{x}} = 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

So I saw this solution to the equation $x + {\frac {1}{x}} = 1$ on a website.It goes something like this:

$\to x + {\frac {1}{x}} = 1$

$\to  {\frac {x^2 +1}{x}} = 1$

$\to x^2 + 1 = x$

$\to x^2 -x +1 = 0$

$\to (x+1)(x^2 - x + 1) = 0$

$\to x^3 + 1^3 = 0$

$\to x^3 = -1$

$\to x = -1$ [end]

But here is where my confusion is , if I plugin $x = -1$ to the original equation $x + {\frac {1}{x}} = 1$ 
 , I get $-2 = 1$ , which is not true.Am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: When you multiply both sides by $x+1$, the implicit assumption you are making is that $x\neq-1$, since otherwise, the step is not reversible. Thus, this proof shows there are no real solutions, other than potentially $x=-1$ (but you showed this isn't the case)

Comment: If it's as you described it, the web site is wrong. The equation has no real number solutions. Note that if $x\le 1$ then $\frac 1x\ge1$ so the sum is always too big.

Comment: @don that step introduces a spurious solution, but its reversibility isn't an issue.

Comment: @MJD reversibility is precisely the issue. These sorts of proofs only work if you can reverse the whole proof, since you need to start with $x=\text{value}$, and end with the equation you attempt to solve to prove that the value is a solution. $x=-1$ isn't necessarily a spurious solution (although in this case, it is).

Comment: This should act as a reminder to check the solutions at the end.  If we were to accept the work shown as correct (*I honestly didn't look over it very hard*), and we see that it implies that $x=-1$ but plugging in $-1$ gives $-2=1$, this means that the initial assumptions were incorrect/impossible, namely here that there even existed a solution to $x+\frac{1}{x}=1$ in the first place.

Comment: I will admit something right now.They didn't actually deduce $x = -1$ from $x^3 = -1$. They just left it as $x^3 = -1$.Then they used it to get the value of $x^{1971} +1/x^{2022}$ . But people who don't know what are even complex numbers(??) (my classmates) might be tempted to deduce $x = -1$ from $x^3 = -1$ , which is wrong. Someone has to tell them that there are no real solutions to the problem (because they are spurious ) and show the complex number solutions. But this is way outside our curriculum .

Comment: Now this is interesting. The video lecture in the website tells me "Think hard about why $x \neq -1$ but $x^3 = -1$ ". I guess they know about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line
$$  (x+1)(x^2−x+1) = 0  $$
has introduced a "[spurious solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions)".

We can make this much more clear.  To the true equation $0=0$, multiply on the left by $x+1$:
$$  (x+1)0 = 0  \text{.}  $$
This equation is still true (it's still $0 = 0$), but if we were to mechanically solve for $x$, we would analyze the product (a product is zero when any of its factors is zero) as "either $x+1 = 0$ or $0 = 0$" and then our attention is wasted finding the solution to the first clause: $x = -1$.  Which is, admittedly a solution, but so is every other choice for $x$, like $7$ or $-\pi$.

So, to the derivation given...  Suppose we could factor our polynomial, so that we had
$$  (x-a)(x-b) = 0  $$
for some numbers $a$ and $b$.  We know this equation has two solutions: $x = a$ and $x = b$ (again, because a product is zero when any of its factors is zero).  We can multiply this by a useless factor
$$  (x-1)(x-a)(x-b) = 0  \text{,}  $$
inserting the [extraneous solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) $x = 1$.

The rules to remember:

- If you divide through an equation by something that can ever be zero, be sure to handle the "that thing is zero" case separately.
- If you multiply through an equation by something that can ever be zero, be sure to check your results for extraneous solutions.

In your case, you checked for an extraneous solution and found that it was extraneous.  (The two roots of the quadratic are the other two, complex, roots of $x^3 + 1 = 0$.  The extraneous root was inserted in the indicated step.)

Comment: Since english is not my mother tongue, I could not find / use this terminology. (extraneous, spurious) This answer is, in my opinion, the best answer and should be accepted.(+1).

Comment: @lonestudent yep.I will accept this.Estraneous solutions is something I am very new to :).They are more weirder to me than complex numbers.

Comment: @Prithu There is always something you can learn from every answer.  Therefore, actually all the answers are always useful.(for me)

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ were real, it has to be positive, since a negative number has to have a negative reciprocal (and their sum will be negative). It is possible to prove that the sum of any real positive number and its reciprocal is at least $2$. So $x$ cannot be a real number.

The incorrect step (as already pointed out in a comment) is that when you multiply by $x+1$, you're assuming $x+1 \ne 0$ which means $x\ne -1$. The multiplication is an unnecessary step, designed to introduce a redundant (real) root and confuse you into accepting a paradoxical solution. All you need to do is solve the quadratic $x^2 - x +1 =0$ by completing the square or formula. The two complex conjugate roots are the only true solutions of the original equation.

These two complex roots are also the complex cube roots of $-1$, which is why they also solve $x^3 = - 1$. But not *every* solution of $x^3 = -1$ solves the original equation, and, as you have already observed, $x=-1$ obviously doesn't. No real number does.

Answer (score 1):

From the fourth line to the fifth line, you are multiplying by $x+1$, which equals zero when $x=-1$.

In fact, you don't even need to multiply by $x+1$ at all. Just solve $x^2-x+1=0$ (which you still need to do anyway when solving $x^3+1=0$, so again there is no point in multiplying the quadratic by $x+1$ at all).

So, $x=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4}}{2}=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}=\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ are the two complex conjugate solutions to $x+\frac{1}{x}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Because, $-1$ is **not** a solution of your original equation.

---

But, Yes!

- If $x^2-x+1=0$, then $x^3=-1$. You showed this.

But, this **doesn't imply** $x=-1$ must be a root of the $x^2-x+1=0$.

It is not acceptable to write that $x^3=-1$, then $x=-1.$

Because, if $x^3=-1$, then we have $3$ different roots. One of them is real, the other two are complex roots.

$$\begin{align}x^2- x+1\require{cancel}\hspace{1em}\cancel{\hspace{-1em}{\iff}\hspace{-1em}}\hspace{1em} &\color{red}{(x+1)}(x^2-x+1)\\
&=x^3+1\end{align}$$

When you multiply the expression $x^2-x+1$ by $(x+1)$, you add $1$ different root to the roots list, which is not the root of the original equation.

In other words, $x^2-x+1$ and $\color{red}{(x+1)}(x^2-x+1)=x^3+1$  are not the equivalent polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$f(x)=0\implies (x-\alpha)f(x)=0\  \forall\alpha\in\Bbb C$$

However, clearly $f(x)\not\equiv 0$ (I.e. it is absurd that $f(\alpha)=0\ \forall \alpha\in\Bbb C$)

In this case, the only two solutions are that of $x^2-x+1=0$. Indeed, since $$(x+1)(x^2-x+1)=x^3+1$$ the solutions you seek are the negatives of the complex cube roots of unity.